# Ribbon Menu with Electron

Tags: javascript, electron, ribbon

I am starting out with [Electron](http://electron.atom.io) and wondered if it was possible to have a Ribbon Menu instead of the built in Menu.  I know how to create a Menu in an Electron application but would like to know if it is possible to have a Ribbon style Menu instead, does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: I've searched for a solution, too. I would recommend to deactivate the native menu and use a third party library as Jens Habegger mentioned. You get cross-platform compatibility for free.

Answer (score 3):

Electron does not offer customization of the current menu implementation beyond the setting of its content.

You can, however, use third party JS/CSS libraries like [dhtmlxRibbon](https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxRibbon/) or [Metro 4](https://metroui.org.ua/). That won't be the actual native ribbon menu implementation, but it will still be cross-system compatible.

Comment: Links are dead :(

Comment: I did some googling and came up with two new projects that do pretty much exactly what the now defunct libraries do.